# SQLite only creates 2 tables

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Because of some reason SQLite only creates two tables instead of 4. I'm using this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String TABLE_RECEIPT            = "CREATE TABLE RECEIPT (receiptId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, receiptDate INTEGER); ";
    db.execSQL(TABLE_RECEIPT);

    String TABLE_PRODUCT            = "CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (productId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, productName TEXT NOT NULL, productImagePath TEXT, productPrice REAL NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(TABLE_PRODUCT);

    String TABLE_RECEIPT_RULE       = "CREATE TABLE RECEIPT_RULE (receiptId INTEGER NOT NULL, productId INTEGER NOT NULL, ruleAmount INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (receiptId, productId), FOREIGN KEY(receiptId) REFERENCES RECEIPT(receiptId), FOREIGN KEY(productId) REFERENCES PRODUCT(productId));";
    db.execSQL(TABLE_RECEIPT_RULE);

    String TABLE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES = "CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES (productId INTEGER NOT NULL, attributeName TEXT NOT NULL, attributeValue TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (productId, attributeName), FOREIGN KEY(productId) REFERENCES PRODUCT(productId));";
    db.execSQL(TABLE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES);

    Log.i(Config.TAG, "Recreated database");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    String TABLE_PRODUCT            = "DROP TABLE PRODUCT;";
    String TABLE_RECEIPT            = "DROP TABLE RECEIPT;";
    String TABLE_RECEIPT_RULE       = "DROP TABLE RECEIPT_RULE;";
    String TABLE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES = "DROP TABLE PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES;";

    db.execSQL(TABLE_PRODUCT);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_RECEIPT);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_RECEIPT_RULE);
    db.execSQL(TABLE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

The message `Recreated database` is visible, so it does try to create all tables. It doesn't show any kind of error.

I don't know if it's usefull, but i'm reading the existing tables with the code below:

```
//Placed in SQLiteStorage
public Cursor showAllTables(){
    String mySql = " SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " + " WHERE type='table'             "
            + "   AND name LIKE 'PR_%' ";
    return db.rawQuery(mySql, null);
}   

//In Activity, create the storage and calls the function 
Cursor c = new SQLiteStorage(this).showAllTables();
if (c.moveToFirst()) 
{
    while(!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        Log.i(Config.TAG, c.getString(0));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like there would be an error if it's missing tables.  Can you put a try.. catch in there to see if it hits an error that might be getting swallowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your showAllTable function, you are selecting all tables that begin with PR so only the product table and product attribute tables show up in your query.

change

String mySql = " SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " + " WHERE type='table'             "
            + "   AND name LIKE 'PR_%' ";

to

String mySql = " SELECT name FROM sqlite_master " + " WHERE type='table'";

Comment: Haha, really didn't saw that. The danger of copy/paste i gues. Thanks!